# Is SQL injection possible here in this given code php - laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have ecommerce store on which there are upto 3 varients of same product so I am storing that the varient in products table like product_varient_1, product_varient_2, product_varient_3

the varient number is supplied by user, one colleague said it is safe since we have not use `selectRaw`

```
    $var = 1;
    $sample = DB::table('products')->select("product_varient_$var")
            ->distinct()
            ->get()
```

Comment: I don't know your full use case, however, personally I would change your database schema so that the varient id is stored as a value in its own column. Consider adding a fourth, fifth or sixth etc. variant. If a product can have multiple varients, then a pivot table might be considered. Doing so would also mitigate your current issue.

Comment: what  @Peppermintology says is correct. But, if you really want to go this path, i will escape like `$var = (int)$var;`. Sure that you have to put some try catch, or else a formrequest to handle only numeric values, but still try catch

Answer (score 0):

You can use validation:

```
$request->validate([
    'varient_id' => 'required|in:1,2,3'
])
```

Addiotianlly, you can check `$var` right before executing query:

```
if(!in_array($var, [1, 2, 3]) {
    return 'No such variation'; // return error what you need
} 
$sample = DB::table('products')->select("product_varient_$var")
        ->distinct()
        ->get()
```